# Wordpress Pods Custom Post Type - separate Media Upload folder for each custom Post Types

Tags: posts, customization

I searched but unable to find the answer. 
I am using Pods Framework for creating custom post types in Wordpress.
I want each user roles to have different media upload folder so like I have a post type 'local news' and another post type 'books' and two user roles like 'news editor' and 'book publisher'.
So when news editor upload images in local news post type then it should not have access to all my images from uploads directory. and same with book publisher.

So they can not see each others media and it will also be easy to manage images with separate folder for each post type. 
*How to achieve this ?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPBeginner appears to have [an article](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-restrict-media-library-access-to-users-own-uploads-in-wordpress/) that addresses what you are talking about. Failing that, you might Google search for "wordpress media access control".  I found several plugins that might work for you.

Comment: Got it!! Thanks :)